# Escape dollar sign in html

Tags: html

I want to display the string `awk '$1==1' test.txt` in the website.

But it doesn't work beacues it contain the `$` symbol.

How could I escape this symbol in html?

Comment: this is not possible, it should work, provide your HTML here

Comment: Pure HTML doesn't treat `$` specially, but you may be using a templating system that does. Try `&#36;` in its place.

Comment: @chepner Oh you answered it before me, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it.

`<p> awk '&#36;1==1' test.txt <\p>`

This will display in the website:

```
awk '$1==1' test.txt
```